# jQuery FadeIn/Out Attributes

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to modify the code below to fadeOut and then FadeIn the removal and adding of the style attribute from body_id.

I know I can fade the whole of body_id but I would like to animate the removal and adding of the style attribute only not everything inside the id itself?

```
$(".bg").click(function(){
var1 = $(this).attr('id');
loc = "background-image:url(" + var1 + ")"

$("#body_id").removeAttr("style").attr("style", loc + ";");
$.cookie('pageBG', loc,{ expires: 7, path: '/'});
return false;
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't change the whole of the style attribute unless you have reason to. You can change individual styles on an element with the .css function, ($('#body_id').css({'background-image',var1}))

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible in this case, since we're talking about a `background-image` here, and there's no way to change the opacity of a `background-image` through CSS.

You can either change the master opacity (`.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut`) of the element or use a separate element positioned in the same position as the background and fade that instead.

---

Separate cleanup of your current code:

```
$(".bg").click(function(){
    var bgUrl = this.id;

    $("#body_id").css('backgroundImage', bgUrl);
    $.cookie('pageBG', bgUrl, { expires: 7, path: '/'});

    return false;
});
```

Remember to change the part of your code that reads out the cookie too.

Comment: Changing the opacity of your element with the fade functions will fade the element and any of it's children. So if you want to just fade the background image, you'll need to place an element at the document root, (Just inside the `<body>` element.) style it to fit the window `body {position: relative;} #bg {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;}` and ensure that you have nothing inside it. That said, you'll need to z-index it to ensure that it is _under_ everything else on the page. Or z-index everything else to be above it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $body_id = $('#body_id');

$body_id.fadeOut(function() {

    // This runs when the fadeOut is complete.
    $body_id.removeAttr('style').fadeIn();

});
```